# Will the angular build include the spec file size?

Tags: angular, build, specifications

For  my micro site development, I want to reduce the bundle size. Will the spec files also gets added when I build the angular or do I need to remove it separately.

Comment: No, it won't get added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec-files are only for testing purposes and of no use when the app is used in production. Thus, they won't get added as well as E2E files.